# Android pairing new Bluetooth device with registerForActivityResult()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In official documentation there is explanation how to pair a new device, https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/companion-device-pairing#kotlin, but the problem is that it is using deprecated code.

In example, they are using `startIntentSenderForResult()` and that is deprecated, so I have tried with `registerForActivityResult()`.

The problem is that app is crashing when i start pairing process. Error is: `...is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.`.

Since I am using Compose, I have created separate Activity for pairing, but the problem stays. When I add `AppLifeCycleObserver()`, and observe behaviour with `Log.i()`, pairing is called after `onResume()`.

Does anyone know how to accomplish pairing with `registerForActivityResult()`?

Code:

```
class PairNewDeviceActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val deviceManager: CompanionDeviceManager by lazy {
        getSystemService(Context.COMPANION_DEVICE_SERVICE) as CompanionDeviceManager
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val deviceFilter: BluetoothDeviceFilter = BluetoothDeviceFilter.Builder()
            .setAddress(MAC_ADDRESS)
            .build()
        val pairingRequest: AssociationRequest = AssociationRequest.Builder()
            .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter)
            .setSingleDevice(true)
            .build()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            val executor = Executor { it.run() }
            deviceManager.associate(
                pairingRequest,
                executor,
                object : CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
                    override fun onAssociationPending(intentSender: IntentSender) {
                        startPairing(intentSender)
                    }

                    override fun onAssociationCreated(associationInfo: AssociationInfo) {}
                    override fun onFailure(error: CharSequence?) {}
                }
            )
        } else {
            deviceManager.associate(
                pairingRequest,
                object : CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
                    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
                    override fun onDeviceFound(intentSender: IntentSender) {
                        startPairing(intentSender)
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(error: CharSequence?) {}

                },
                null
            )
        }

        setContent {
            SomeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    PairNewBluetoothDevice()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun startPairing(sender: IntentSender) {
        val startPairing =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) {
                if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    val deviceToPair: BluetoothDevice? =
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                            it.data?.getParcelableExtra(
                                BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE,
                                BluetoothDevice::class.java
                            )
                        } else @Suppress("DEPRECATION") {
                            it.data?.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                        }

                    deviceToPair?.createBond()
                }
            }

        val intent = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(sender).build()

        startPairing.launch(intent)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Edit:

Code in compose, but the `btToPair` is null.

```
@Composable
fun PairNewBluetoothDevice() {
val macAddress = MAC_ADDRESS_FROM_VIEWMODEL

val context: Context = LocalContext.current
val deviceManager: CompanionDeviceManager =
    getSystemService(context, CompanionDeviceManager::class.java) as CompanionDeviceManager
val deviceFilter: BluetoothDeviceFilter = BluetoothDeviceFilter.Builder()
    .setAddress(macAddress)
    .build()
val associationRequest: AssociationRequest = AssociationRequest.Builder()
    .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter)
    .setSingleDevice(true)
    .build()

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
val pairingRequest = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
    onResult = { result: ActivityResult ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val btToPair: BluetoothDevice? =
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) result.data?.getParcelableExtra(
                    BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE,
                    BluetoothDevice::class.java
                ) else @Suppress("DEPRECATION") result.data?.getParcelableExtra(
                    BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE
                )

            btToPair?.createBond()
        }
    }
)
val versionTiramisuPlus = object : CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
    override fun onAssociationPending(intentSender: IntentSender) {
        pairingRequest.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build())
    }

    override fun onAssociationCreated(associationInfo: AssociationInfo) {}

    override fun onFailure(error: CharSequence?) {}

}
val versionNotTiramisuPlus = object : CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
    @Deprecated(
        "Deprecated in Java", ReplaceWith(
            "pairingRequest.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build())",
            "androidx.activity.result.IntentSenderRequest"
        )
    )
    override fun onDeviceFound(intentSender: IntentSender) {
        pairingRequest.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build())
    }

    override fun onFailure(error: CharSequence?) {}

}

val callBack =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) versionTiramisuPlus else versionNotTiramisuPlus

Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {

    Button(onClick = {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            val executor = Executor { it.run() }
            deviceManager.associate(
                associationRequest,
                executor,
                callBack
            )
        } else {
            deviceManager.associate(
                associationRequest,
                callBack,
                null
            )
        }

    }) {
        Text(text = "Pair...")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you read the [Get a result from an activity guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) which explains why you need to unconditionally call `registerForActivityResult` as part of the creation of your activity and not at the same time as you call `launch`? Did you see [documentaton on the Activity Result APIs for Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#activity_result) which explain how to do this request as part of your composable itself, without a separate activity?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, thanks for the links. Especially for the second link, the first link I've seen before. I've managed to get it to show me the pairing request prompt. In the `onResult` of the `rememberLauncherForActivityResult`, the value of `btToPair` is `null`. I can not figure out why I get that value. I've edited the first post to show code for pairing through compose. Once again, thank you. Even though I did not get a positive result, I've learned something new.